# Авторизация из скрипта

Tags: google-apps-script

Возможно ли произвести авторизацию для другого аккаунта из гугл скрипта, к примеру: что бы пользователи могли обращаться к гугл контактам, со своих аккаунтов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть три пути:

1. Необходимо опубликовать скрипт от своего имени для всех, у кого есть аккаунт Google [Deploying a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app)
2. Передать пользователю скрипт (Таблицу, Документ, Презентацию со встроенным скриптом) для редактирования, чтобы он запускал функцию от своего имени.
3. Реализовать процесс аутентификации самостоятельно.

Третий пункт лучше вообще не рассматривать как потенциально возможный.

Comment: У меня проблема не передать скрипт, а именно получить доступ к другому общему аккаунту, а точнее в конактах, что бы там вносить изменения

Comment: Тогда только через первый вариант. Одна из разновидностей первого варианта - дополнение. Но это все равно строить веб апп. Попробуйте задать задачу тут https://plus.google.com/communities/103356854721490738172 или тут https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=@googleappsscriptrc

Comment: Спасибо, я только допёр, что ты имел ввиду. норм решение, через doGet()